# JavaScript Error : Object is not supporting the property progressbar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have a problem with JavaScript the jquery progressbar. The error is that the object would not support the property progressbar. I have tried everything from other posts with same problems but nothing works :(

I have also checked that the jquery files were correctly loaded.

In the Create.cshtml at the bottom is the code for the progressbar.

This is the Create.cshtml

```
@model ContosoTelephonebookContext.TelephoneBook

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "TelephoneBook", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ad</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>     
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="imageFile">Image file</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="imageFile" accept="image/*" class="form-control fileupload" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="StartInvoicing();" class="btn btn-default" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 37
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="progressbar"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>

    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;

            // client-side sendMessage function that will be called from the server-side
            progressNotifier.client.sendMessage = function(message, count) {
                // update progress
                UpdateProgress(message, count);
                alert(count);
            };

            // establish the connection to the server and start server-side operation
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
                // call the method CallLongOperation defined in the Hub
                progressNotifier.server.getCountAndMessage();
            });
        });

// Update the progress bar 
        function UpdateProgress(message, count) {
            var result = $("#result");
            result.html(message);
            $("#progressbar").data("progressbar").value(count);
        }
    </script>   
}
```

And this is the _layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Company Telephone Book</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Company Telephonebook", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("TelephoneBook", "Index", "Telephonebook")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Statistik", "Index", "Statistic")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Company telephone book</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I would be thankful you for your support

Now i have create a mvce to make it easier to analyse the problem.

I have created a empty MVC web project and only add the needed functions

Here is the _layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Meine ASP.NET-Anwendung</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Anwendungsname", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Startseite", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Info", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Kontakt", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("test", "Index", "Test")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Meine ASP.NET-Anwendung</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And the test.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<div id="progressbar"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                value: 37
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

I have the same error again

Hello Thanks for the solution. Here is the complete solution how it works now. I added the correct versions to the bundleconfig class.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Verwenden Sie die Entwicklungsversion von Modernizr zum Entwickeln und Erweitern Ihrer Kenntnisse. Wenn Sie dann
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you move the script with the progressbar function call into the Script section after the ~/bundles/jqueryval is included?

Comment: Hello thanks i have tried it but the same error again

Comment: Please create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello thanks yes i have the same error with the mvcei post the issus iabove in the question

Comment: Well, edit the question to include the mcve. (completely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that two versions of jQuery are loaded.

One version is loaded here:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js")
```

Another version is loaded here:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

One quick solution is to just replace the later call with your code. So, replace the line from the second example with your other code (that you then delete), so that the end of _Layout.cshtml looks like this:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

A better solution is to actually change the code in BundleConfig.RegisterBundles, so that the jquery version you want to use and jquery ui are loaded together via the bundle mechanism.

Also note, that for the progressbar to work, you also need to include the CSS files that are part of jQuery ui.